# Can websites share data stored on the client-side?

Tags: security, cookies, web

Is there any way for a website to communicate with another storing data on the browser?

I think cookies are strictly available to the same domain (and subdomains), but I notice suspicious cases in which websites seem to be able to track my presence on another site.

I also have NoScript to block per-site JavaScripts.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely they are using Third-party Cookie or Super-Cookie. If you're not sure what these mean, check out their definitions on Wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Supercookie
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Privacy_and_third-party_cookies

Comment: That's really scary; I will look into disabling them into Firefox. I'll have a look at the links later, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, via [3rd party cookies](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/disable-third-party-cookies). Here's a simplistic example:

Imagine if the sites you visit contain this code:

```html
<script src="//tracker.example.com/foo.js"></script>
```

`foo.js` is dynamically generated. If no cookie is sent by the browser to the `tracker.example.com` domain, then a unique ID is generated and stored in a cookie.

e.g. the cookie is set by an HTTP response header to assign the user a new, globally unique ID:

```
Set-Cookie: userid=d68267df-35f4-4443-9d8a-3afeebdf8f95
```

On a subsequent request to `foo.js` including the cookie value from the browser, the `foo.js` code could set a variable based on this cookie value.

```js
var userId = 'd68267df-35f4-4443-9d8a-3afeebdf8f95';
```

This allows the site to track all actions under this ID. e.g. The domain `example.net` could then set its own cookie with that userId, so anything the user does is logged by that ID (clicking `example.net/shiny_thing` will now have the ID set in the cookie).

Therefore if two websites, `example.net` and `example.org`, use this script called from `tracker.example.com` and use the same backend data-store, they would be able to track your activity and know that userId `d68267df-35f4-4443-9d8a-3afeebdf8f95` clicked on foo, bar and foobar on `example.org`, and cicked on shiny thing on `example.net`.

If you have JavaScript disabled then this type of tracking is more difficult, but not impossible. The best way is to disable 3rd party cookies rather than relying on JavaScript being disabled.